# Как изменить цвет текста у виджета EditText, в состоянии enabled (false)?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Как изменить цвет текста у виджета EditText, в состоянии enabled(false)?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужен селектор:

1. Создайте файл `example.xml` в папке `res/drawable`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="@color/disabled_color" />
    <item android:color="@color/normal_color"/>
</selector>
```

2. Укажите этот файл как цвет текста для нужной вьюхи:

```
<EditText
    android:text="whatever text you want"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/example" />
```